# Is there a way to get the MethodDescription that matched?

Tags: byte-buddy

I'm "in" the `intercept()` method of `DynamicType.Builder`, right "after" a method has matched in the `method()` method.  For example:

```
builder
  .method(elementMatcher)
  .intercept(/* here I am! */)
```

For a variety of reasons, I need the `MethodDescription` that was matched to be available "inside" that `intercept()` invocation.  Is there any recipe that will give it to me?

I think I can probably abuse [`ElementMatchers#cached(ElementMatcher, ConcurrentMap)`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.22/net/bytebuddy/matcher/ElementMatchers.html#cached-net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatcher-java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap-) for this but I stress "abuse".

Answer (score 0):

The *intercept* method takes an `Implementation` which in turn returns a `ByteCodeAppender`. The latter accepts the instrumented method as an argument. You can use `Implementation.Simple` to direcly supply a byte code appender.

Comment: Normally I'm good at connecting the dots.  But not here.  I don't see how if I'm creating an `Implementation` of any kind—I don't see how to get the `MethodDescription` from what was matched by the `ElementMatcher`.

Comment: Within `.intercept(/* here I am! */)`, you supply an `Implementation` which returns a `ByteCodeAppender` which supplied the method that was previously matched.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. Inside `method()`, I might have: `ElementMatchers.named("fred")`.  How do I get a `MethodDescription` out of an `ElementMatcher.Junction`, which is what `named` returns, so that I can create an `Implementation` to then somehow pass to `intercept()`?  (In any event, I worked around the problem by doing my own matching, but I'm still curious.)

Comment: Not sure if I follow. You get the same `MethodDescription` passed to both the `method` and the `intercept` methods. In the latter, it's only indirect via the created `ByteCodeAppender`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your patience; I am not smart enough to see it.  :-(  I don't want to waste any more of your time.

Comment: Nah, we're likely speaking about two different tbings. Could you extend your question, maybe I figure out what your problem really is.